# Python all permutations of array rows possible

Tags: python, permutation

i am new to python and have a problem i can't solve on myself.
I do have an array with 3 colums and 20 rows. I want to create files that contain every row
permutation possible but only between the first 10 and the last 10 lines.

so i want to swap the first 10 rows and create every permutation possible and for every of this files i want to swap the 10 last rows with each other and create outputfiles with this permutations.

I would really appreciate every idea!
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There are a couple of issues with your question. First up, you didn't `tag` Python, making it hard for Python developers to find your question (I have fixed this for you). Secondly, you need to show some code so that people can help you. We don't write code here, we help people with existing code or provide alternatives to existing code.

Comment: http://sscce.org/ will help you greatly

Comment: (Give an example input and output, probably with smaller numbers.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly what you want!

I hope it's helpful.

```
import itertools
itertools.permutations([1,2,3])
```